# Java swing multiple cards in one JFrame

Tags: java, swing, bookmarks

I want to have multiple cards/bookmarks/pins/windows inside one jframe, just like here:

[image: Screenshot from chrome]

I cant find anything anywhere, just name of this feature in Java should be enough, I'll google the rest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for `JTabbedPane`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i have been looking for :)